# Vue / Vuetify: get dimensions of v-flex

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify has the `v-resize` directive, and the example shows how to use it with window size.

How can I use it to monitor the size of a component therein (e.g. v-flex).

In the linked codesandbox the goal is to set the svg width / height = to the v-flex width and height.

[image: Edit Vuetify get width of v-flex]

Answer (score 0):

Your code in the demo is incorrect, you're saving the `onResize()` results into `this.windowSize`, but you're referencing `mx` and `my` in the `template`.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container dark grid-list-md text-xs-center>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 v-resize="onResize">
          <v-card color="primary"> <svg></svg> </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
      mounted x: {{ windowSize.x }} mounted y: {{ windowSize.y }}
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Test",
  data: () => ({ windowSize: { x: 0, y: 0, mx: 0, my: 0 } }),
  methods: {
    onResize() {
      this.windowSize = { x: window.innerWidth, y: window.innerHeight };
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.onResize();
  }
};
</script>
```

Here, I fixed your sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/k53oyn3n07

Comment: Not incorrect..., I’ve read in other posts that using ref doesn’t work when component is mounted so I kept mount separate in case I run into that issue... also I just showed how to do it with window size. The question is about monitoring v-flex element